# Box2dWeb: must fixtures be destroyed explicitly when destroying the body?

Tags: box2d, memory, body

I use b2WorldObj.DestroyBody(bodyObj) to destroy the body when it is not needed anymore. The body has one fixture attached to it.

Do I need to destroy the fixture before destroying the body? or should I assume that by destroying the body all its fixtures will be automatically destroyed?

Right now, I do not destroy the fixtures explicitly and the game runs fine. But my concern is more about memory leaks. I want to make sure that all the bodies and fixtures that are not used anymore are completely removed from the memory. How can I best achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just have read the manual, you know.

Citation from the manual, chapter 7, section 7.2, page 35 :

> You can destroy a fixture on the parent body. You may do this to model a breakable object. Otherwise you can just leave the fixture alone and let the body destruction take care of destroying the attached fixtures

Comment: I spent some time to search online before asking the question here, but could not find the answer. I guess I had to go straight to the manual. Thanks for answering.

Comment: *Always* go straight to the manual and if you cannot find anything in the table of contents or in the likely related document sections, *then* you can search on google & cie and ask a question here if you still can't find the answer.